# Improvement of list comparison algorithm complexity

Tags: java, arrays, performance, algorithm

I have two arrays `array1 = Array<List<Integer>>` and `array2 = Array<Integer>` and I traverse `array2`. Then I try to find in which list from `array1` the current item in `array2` could be. I retrieve that corresponding list from `array1` and traverse it to see if I can find a similar number in `array1`. I define similarity as equal numbers within some error epsilon (i.e `6` would be found equal to `7` with `epsilon=1` since `7-6=1`). If the numbers are equal I added them to a list called `matchList`. At the end I have a list of `matchList`s called `resultList`.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  int index = array2[i] % n;
  List<Integer> currentList = array1[index];
  List<Integer> matchList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

  while(int currentItem : currentList) {
    if (currentItem - array2[i] < epsilon){
      matchList.add(currentItem);
    }
  }

  if (!matchList.isEmpty()){
    resultList.add(matchList);
  }
}
```

My question is if I could improve this `O(n*m)` algoritm's complexity. I've already greatly improved the speed of the algorithm by preallocating arrays, using iterators for traversing linked lists and by using primitive type collection (Trove instead of Java's built-ins) and some other measures.

Edit: I'm interested only in suggestions which improve the big-O runtime.

Comment: This is not even Java code. Containment checks are usually better implemented by saving values in temporary hash tables what allows a more efficient lookup of existant values. At best, you can improve the runtime to O(n + m) this way.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do containment checks in this case is to use a tree for range queries. ie: is x within epsilon of y. Can you elaborate on your hashmap idea? Hashing requires an exact match and as a result don't see how it can be used.

Comment: If you use Java 8 you could use parallel stream to make it run faster. You need to make sure that underlying collections support parallel streams.

Comment: Is `epsilon` an invariant of the method?

Comment: You could sort the 2 lists. That way if the first matching index in array1 is the index 56 for the current element of array2, then you can start at index 56 for the next element, reducing the number of comparisons more and more.

Comment: This is a part of an algo for elasticsearch which is a distributed framework so parallelism does not come into question; however I'm trying to improve the algo itself which helps more than throwing cores at it.

Comment: _unfold_ your structure into a `HashMap<Int, Int>` where the key is the value in the `array1` sub array and the value is the index of the sub array in `array1`. This way search will be `O(e)` where `e` is the chosen epsilon.

Comment: @ssedano yes epsilon is a small constant <1

Comment: @Adrian if you are dealing with `int`, how does an epsilon `<1` work? In any case - `Map` to the rescue once again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know what you mean; I adapted the code presented here from my actual code and it seems I made them all ints where in fact the arrays presented here hold indexes to the actual data.

Comment: Given that you are using floats, seems like a range query on a binary tree would work well. Should be around O(N log N + m log N) if you make a tree out of the elements in array1 or O(N log M + M log M) if you make a tree out of the elements in array2. N is the total number of elements in array1 and M is the total number of elements in array2.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this algorithmically (simply running your algorithm parallelly as suggested in the comments does not decrease your algorithmic complexity) you would need to introduce a more efficient data structure which allows you to perform a faster look-up.

You would first create buckets where each bucket contains values in a given range (`value` plus/minus `epsilon`). A list value could therefore be in several buckets. You can create this bucket list in at least `O(n * #buckets)`, maybe less depending on whether you have an assumption on the distribution of your values.

Next you can check your other list against these buckets. Depending on the ratio of your range and the amount of values for these buckets, it might be efficient to create the buckets lazily and organize the buckets themselves in some sort of hash table. You would then traverse the other list and check the buckets for their containing values which can be done in `O(m)` time.

This leaves you with `O(n * #buckets + m)` in total.